# HTML input form to python list

Tags: python, html, forms

I want to create a HTML form (with multiple checkboxes) and pass the output as a list to my python function.

Sorry for being a total n00b, but I need help.

Comment: Consider reading these two links https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp and https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex51.html

Comment: your question is too broad, at least try making a html layout and then ask specific question dear- we would like to help but not solve all your work without you trying;

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam precisely why I announced the noobness.
Even a good resource would help

Comment: check out web.py, this example is for forms: http://webpy.org/form. Django is another web framework for python, here's the resource for forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/
I would say web.py is easier for starting out though. Come back and ask a more specific question once you've tried out one of these examples, and I'll be happy to help.